# Running shell script before downloading dependencies of rpm?

Tags: shell, gradle, centos, rpm, yum

Here i'm building rpm using gradle.i'm using [nebula.ospackage](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin) . Is there any way a that i can run shell script before downloadig httpd.

```
buildRpm {
dependsOn "extractApps", "extractConfig"

requires('httpd')
requires('mod_ssl')
requires('mod_wsgi')


preInstall file("${projectDir}/scripts/preinstall.sh")
postInstall file("${projectDir}/scripts/postinstall.sh")
}
```

in simple terms run shell script before require runs?

Answer (score 1):

There are no scripts in *.rpm packages that are run before dependencies are checked by rpm (or downloads are initiated by gradle).

You need to focus on either gradle (or yum) for your request. RPM isn't the right place.